# ways to wear x pairs of red and y pairs of green socks for (x+y) days

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have x pairs of red socks and y pairs of green socks to wear for (x+y) days.

How many ways can you wear these socks (one pair each day)?
For example, first day : green, second : green, third: red ...

(Note: you cannot mix colors! That is, you can't  wear one green sock and one red sock on each foot)

Comment: If you wear green socks on the first day and green on the second, you are not alternating colors.

Comment: $$\binom{x+y}x$$

Comment: sorry, I didbn't mean "alternate". bad word choice. updating now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply,
$$\binom{x+y}{x}$$ 
All you are doing is choosing the days that you are wearing red socks: there are $x+y$ total socks (same as the number of days), and the other days you must wear green. 
Similarly,
$$\binom{x+y}{y}$$
In the case, out of the total number of socks/days, you are picking the green socks to wear.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the answer? Is the answer the sum of these two? How did you come up with it? (I don't just need the solution, I need to understand how it was come up with) Thank you

Comment: Oooh! That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: $\binom{n}{k}$ (pronounced, "n choose k" is the number of ways of choosing k things from a set of n things, and it stands for $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ where "!" stands for factorial, $n(n-1)(n-2)...(2)(1)$. This works because $n!$ is the number of ways of ordering n things, and you divide out by all the ways you can reorder all the $k$ things you're choosing out of the $n$ total (wearing green the first and green the second, is the same as wearing the second green set first and the second first, etc., ...